# @Html.Action doesn't print the action result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor view in which I want to render the result of another action. So what I tried doing is this

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "Portal" })
```

However this doesn't seem to render anything on the page. But when I check which URL is rendered by the `Url.Action` with the same parameters it's giving me the proper URL.

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "Portal" }) // this shows /Portal/Blog/Index
@Html.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "Portal" }) // this doesn't show anything
```

And if I go in my browser to `/Portal/Blog/Index` I can see content I'm trying to load just fine. I've even tried removing all of the code from `HomeController` so the action is simply

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // also tried returning this.PartialView() but it makes no difference
    return this.View();
}
```

and the `Index.cshtml` is just

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: `@Html.Action()` is for rendering a child action so your `Index()` method should return `PartialView()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've changed the method to return `PartialView()` instead of a `View()` but that the behavior is still the same - no content rendered, and no error shown.

Comment: If you're going to replace the entire Index page, why not just return a different action from your Index action?

Comment: The idea is that the same action is going to be used to load the initial part of the page and then additional content (loading news items), I've made it so simple just to show that the problem is not in the logic of the controller - my final solution will have much more in the controller than just the return statement.

Comment: Your said _..go in my browser to /Portal/Blog/Index.._ but then _..removing all of the code from HomeController.._ (not BlogController). Are you actually refering to the correct ontroller/action?

Comment: Can't find any reason for that neither. Pretty sure the area registration is fine, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. As mentioned I can access it via URL and also Url.Action resolves it fine.

Comment: First, the fact that you can access via URL doesn't truly mean anything. Child actions don't utilize the routing framework. However, since you were able to see that the action works, it should work just as well as a child. I'd look at the view that attempts to render this child action and its associated action instead as the source of the problem. Perhaps the view you think is getting used is not and therefore this code doesn't exist. Also, for what it's worth, if you return `PartialView` instead of `View`, you don't need to set `Layout` to null.